# How to export favorites from Edge to Firefox bookmarks?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, microsoft-edge, windows-10-v1703

Is there any way to export favorites from Edge in Windows 10 to Firefox?  I have tried going to Edge settings in favorites but the only option there offered to me is import.  I also have gone to Firefox, favorites, and selected import from edge.  I get a folder in favorites labeled windows edge but that folder is empty.

Comment: There are some good tutorials out there that show you how to export Edge favorites to an HTML file.  You can then open that file to double-check that your favorite bookmarks are there before you import it into Firefox:  [How to Import or Export Microsoft Edge Favorites as HTML File in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/38112-microsoft-edge-favorites-import-export-html-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: How do I find what build I have of Windows 10?  I goto settings--windows update, and I have the latest updates but only the last few downloaded files listed, no build number.  Also if I go per the instructions linked to "my" windows 10 edge browser in settings---favorites I am only given the option to import favorites; there is no export option.

Comment: Nevermind I got the answer to the preceding question.  I am running build 14393.693 version 1607.  My problem still remains the same.  I am given the option to import favorites from edge; no option to export..  Oh, and to answer my build question I went to settings, system, about.

Comment: I normally just do `WinKey + R` and type `winver`, but just like many other things in Windows, you can do it several different ways.  I took a closer look at that tutorial, and after receiving feedback from readers the author realized that it worked on his Windows Insider versions and emphasized that it only works *"Starting Windows 10 Build 14926."*  In other words, the mainstream Windows 10 world won't see `Export` options until the Creators Update is released in April.  Sorry about the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Since the [public release](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-info.aspx) of the **Windows 10 Creators Update (version 1703)**, this is now possible:

> 1. Open **Microsoft Edge**.
> 2. Click/tap on the **More** button, and click/tap on **Settings**.
>
> [image: Edge Settings Screen 1]
>
> 3. Click/tap on the **Import from another browser** button under **Import favorites and other info**.
>
> [image: Edge Settings Screen 2]
>
> 4. Click/tap on the **Export to file** button under **Import or export a file**.
>
> [image: Edge Export to a File]
>
> 5. Browse to and select the folder where you want to save the .html file to, type a name you want for the .html file, and click/tap on **Save**.
>
> [image: Edge Save HTML]
>
> 6. Your favorites from Microsoft Edge have now been exported as the .html file.
>
> [image: Edge Save HTML Finished]

After than, you can easily **import your Edge bookmarks into Firefox** in the following manner:

> 1. Click the Bookmarks button [image: Bookmarks Button] and select **Show All Bookmarks** to open the Library window.
> 2. From the toolbar on the Library window, click **Import and Backup** and choose **Import Bookmarks from HTML...**.
>    [image: Import Bookmarks from HTML]
> 3. In the Import Bookmarks File window that opens, navigate to the bookmarks HTML file you are importing and select the file.
> 4. Click the **Open** button. The Import Bookmarks File window will close.
> 5. Close the Library window.

**Sources**:
[TenForums - How to Import or Export Microsoft Edge Favorites as HTML File in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/38112-import-export-favorites-html-file-microsoft-edge.html)
[Mozilla Support - Import Bookmarks from an HTML file](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/import-bookmarks-html-file)